# Autofill Scanned PDF from PHP Form

Tags: php, pdf

I have a scanned pdf. The top of the pdf is a signed form and the bottom is a section that people can sign to subscribe to the contract. I have a form that can autopopulate the bottom portion although, since it is a scanned pdf, it has no form fields. Does anyone have a solution where using PHP a person can fill out the form and then autopopulate the bottom of the pdf with the data or create a layer over it with the data and merge it into one pdf. Another option possibly is to automatically add the top portion as an image with the form below it. Thank you in advance for your help.

[Here is a link to a sample pdf](https://sdpc.a4l.org/addendums/Mathletics_Mathseeds_ExhibitETEC.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to write text into a *template* PDF file. See [this example](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/simple-demo/#p-117).